# UWP BTLE: Cannot read device advertisements

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I am new to this UWP, so bear with me please. I modified the code in the following MS GitHub: [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement/js/js/scenario1_Watcher.js) to create a Windows Phone App that can 'watch' BTLE advertisements.

But it is not able to read it any advertisements. My phone does support BTLE, I am able to see the devices in Windows BT Settings so the device is advertising it too. Please help me find where I am wrong and why.

Here is my code for JS:

```
var watcher = new Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
//watcher.signalStrengthFilter.inRangeThresholdInDBm = -70;
//watcher.signalStrengthFilter.outOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75;
//watcher.signalStrengthFilter.outOfRangeTimeout = 2000;

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("HERE: ready");
    watcher.onreceived = onAdvertisementReceived;
    $("button#start").unbind('click').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('CLICKED >');
        e.preventDefault();
        watcher.start();
    });
    $("button#stop").unbind('click').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('CLICKED <');
        e.preventDefault();
        watcher.stop();
    });
});
function onAdvertisementReceived(eventArgs) {
    console.log("HERE: function watcher", eventArgs);
    var timestamp = eventArgs.timestamp;
    var advertisementType = eventArgs.advertisementType;
    var rssi = eventArgs.rawSignalStrengthInDBm;
    var localName = eventArgs.advertisement.localName;
    $("div#list > ul").append("<li> Timestamp: <strong>" + timestamp.getHours() + ":" + timestamp.getMinutes() +
        ":" + timestamp.getSeconds() + "</strong> Type:" + advertisementType.toString() + " RSSI:" + rssi.toString() + " Name:" +
        localName + "</li>");
}
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bluetooth LE Smart Watch</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>List of BTLE Devices</h4>
        <button class="btn" id="start">Start Watcher</button><button class="btn" id="stop">Stop Watcher</button>
        <div id="list" class="col m12 s12">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it is not able to read it any advertisements. My phone does support BTLE, I am able to see the devices in Windows BT Settings so the device is advertising it too. Please help me find where I am wrong and why.

To get the BTLE work, you need to enable the BlueTooth capability in `package.appxmannifest`. You can achieve this through:

In VS2015->Double click `package.appxmannifest`->Capabilities->Check Bluetooth capability.

Or You can open `package.appxmannifest` in code view and add `<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />` in Capabilities tag:

```
<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
</Capabilities>
```